# android-a gallery like google music player

Tags: android, animation, gallery

I need to make an image gallery like the one in google music player. the user can swipe horizontally and the images move. I searched a lot but didn't find any hint or start point. any help?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a coverflow like gallery. Check out some example like this:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

But you can also looks for opensource projects or examples all around the web. Remember! Google is your friend:

```
android coverflow site:github.com

android coverflow example
```

etc etc